# Random image with Cycle

Tags: 7, entities, media

I'm using Drupal [Cycle](https://drupal.org/project/cycle) module and list field_images items. I check 'random' button, but it is not working. I want get random image every refresh page. How can do it? field_sort_items or anyway solution?

Comment: In the view the sort criteria should be global: random

Comment: I don't use Views.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in lots and lots of ways. This is 1 way without Views.

I did this for a homepage. I made 5 variables that hold `FIDs` for files uploaded using FAPI `file_managed` fapi element in an admin settings form.

Then using `hook_page_build` if I'm on the homepage I created a render array that simply calls `theme_image` using a random file id by loading my 5 variables into an array and using PHP's `array_rand()` to extract 1 random array value.

Lastly, if you can get this far -- and you have page caching turned on ... you'll only get 1 image ever and it'll never be random. For the render array inserted using `hook_page_build` you have to set `#cache => FALSE` within the render array so Drupal will not cache your images and it will be random every pageload.

Answer (score 0):

If you used views, you might try [Views Javascript Random](http://drupal.org/project/views_javascript_random) module  which randomizes on the client side.  Sadly, it looks like it is only for D6.

> Adds a new sort type to views. It's under sort criteria -> Global: Javascript Random.